# I would like to stop a timer (discord)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am new in this world and I am trying things.

I was trying to build a timer bot... And now I have a little problem, I would like to stop my timer whenever I want.

```
bot.on('message', message => {
let timer = setInterval(() => {
    if (message.content.startsWith('!start'))
        message.channel.send("I print something");
}, 10 * 1000)

if (message.content.startsWith('!stop')) {
    message.channel.send("Interaval Cleared");
    clearInterval(timer);
}})
```

When I type !stop in my discord channel, it displays me the message but it doesn't stop my timer... I tried with a return; but it didn't work.

Could you help me please ?

Thanks,

Have a good day !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're starting a new interval each time you run the function. Also, your `timer` value is scoped to each function call, and not "shared" between calls, you need to make it available between them. The behavior you want should look something like this instead:

```
bot = {}
bot.timer = 0; // ensures clearInterval doesn't throw an error if bot.timer hasn't been set
bot.listen = message =>{
    if(message == 'start'){
        clearInterval(bot.timer);   // stops the interval if it been previously started
        bot.timer = setInterval(()=>console.log('I print something'),1000)
    }
    if(message == 'stop') clearInterval(bot.timer);
}
```

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for your help ! 
I adapted the code you gave me with what I want to display on the discord channel, I understand it now but I still have a question:
Why do I have to clear the interval in my first if condition ? I tried to delete it and it still works.

Could you please explain me ?

Comment: Oh! It may be that if I want to set the timer again, its clear the previous timer ?

Comment: Yes, if you didn't clear it, and you run `start` twice, the first interval would keep running, and the `bot.timer` variable would contain the interval id of the second timer. If you run `stop` the second one would be stopped but the first one would not